# Parse JSON Array Object into a JSON Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON Array Object in the following form

```
{"Object1":[
    {"field1":"label1", "field2":"Name1"}, 
    {"field1":"label2", "field2":"Name2"},
    {"field1":"label3", "field2":"Name3"}
]}
```

I want to convert this to

```
{"label1":"Name1", "label2":"Name2", "label3":"Name3"}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any specific problem in doing that?

Comment: this is your predefine format of java.

Comment: I am trying to search information from LDAP server using ldapjs. The JSONArrayObject is the result of JSON.stringify(). I am trying to figure out how to convert to the format I want using JSON.parse()/stringify() or anything else which I dont know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving this 
This will work for you

//assign this to any variable

```
  var obj={"Object1":[
     {"field1":"label1", "field2":"Name1"}, 
    {"field1":"label2", "field2":"Name2"},
    {"field1":"label3", "field2":"Name3"}
]};
//Now take an array
try{
var arr=obj.Object1;
 var newObj={};

  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
  {
   newObj[arr[i].field1]=arr[i].field2;
  }

  alert(JSON.stringify(newObj));

}
 catch(err){alert(err.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty object, then iterate over the `Object1` object and for each object in it add to the empty array the key in `field1` with value in `field2`.

Something like:

```
var _obj = {};
jQuery.each(obj.Object1, function(k, v) {
    _obj[v.field1] = v.field2;
});
```

Comment: "Create an empty **object**..."?

Comment: Since Object1 is a list, you can just use `obj.Object1.forEach(function(v){...})`

Comment: That should do the job, but importing jQuery only do do that is not necessary I think ?

Answer (score 0):

**Something in pure JS with a basic `for loop`** : http://jsfiddle.net/1c911ebr/

```
var object = {"Object1":[
    {"field1":"label1", "field2":"Name1"}, 
    {"field1":"label2", "field2":"Name2"},
    {"field1":"label3", "field2":"Name3"}
]},
    content = object["Object1"],
    newObj = {};


for(var i=0; i<content.length; i++){    
    newObj[content[i].field1] = content[i].field2;    
}
```

Will return :

```
{label1: "Name1", label2: "Name2", label3: "Name3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {"Object1":[
    {"field1":"label1", "field2":"Name1"}, 
    {"field1":"label2", "field2":"Name2"},
    {"field1":"label3", "field2":"Name3"}
]};

function getJSONObj()
{
    var gList = eval("(" + json + ")");   
    var jsonObj = {};
    $.each(gList.Object1, function (keyData, valueData)
    {
        jsonObj[valueData.field1] = valueData.field2;
    });
}
getJSONObj();
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"label1":"Name1", "label2":"Name2", "label3":"Name3"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try, Pure javascript based solution.

```
 var gList= {"Object1":[
    {"field1":"label1", "field2":"Name1"}, 
    {"field1":"label2", "field2":"Name2"},
    {"field1":"label3", "field2":"Name3"}
]};

function transform(){
    var arr = [];

    for(var i=0;i<gList.Object1.length;i++){
        arr.push("'" + gList.Object1[i].field1 + "':'" + gList.Object1[i].field2 + "'");
    }
    alert(arr);
}
```

**Output**

```
'label1':'Name1','label2':'Name2','label3':'Name3
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/de5xoe3r/)

Comment: Yes @undefined, in this demo i created json in string. please check. seriously.

Comment: OP has parsed/clean JavaScript structure, you have converted a valid structure to an _invalid_ JSON and forcefully used `eval` to convert it to JavaScript. Not only this doesn't answer the question but it's also an _anti-pattern_.

Comment: Yes, is there a reason why you put the object in a string, then reconvert it to an object ? (that's a real question :) )

Comment: Updated answer. removed eval() function.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code.

```
var json = "{'Object1':["+
    "{'field1':'label1', 'field2':'Name1'},"+
    "{'field1':'label2', 'field2':'Name2'},"+
    "{'field1':'label3', 'field2':'Name3'}"+
"]}";


function getJSONObj(){
     var gList = eval("(" + json + ")");   
    var jsonObj = {};

    for(var i=0;i<gList.Object1.length;i++){
        jsonObj[gList.Object1[i].field1 ] = gList.Object1[i].field2;
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
}


getJSONObj();
```

**Link -** http://jsfiddle.net/de5xoe3r/5/